# Does Android's Stock Browser support CSS3 transforms?

Tags: android, css

Does Android Stock Browser support CSS3 transforms?

According to this you can: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Im testing on the 'Ice Cream Sandwich' OS and it doesnt seem to work. 
Chrome does seem to work, but the stock browser doesn't.

Can someone point me to some documentation or give me their experiences on this? Can't find any stats on that stock browser. Thank you.

Comment: You might also consider including http://modernizr.com to explicitly check if a feature is available.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using CSS3 Transforms on Android on a mobile site I'm building. You do need to use the WebKit prefix for them to work. i.e. -webkit-transform: skewX(35deg)

[MDN Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

[CSS3 Animations: the Hiccups and Bugs You’ll Want to Avoid](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid/)

Comment: Thanks. Going to update my question. In Chrome on 'Ice Cream Sandwich' transforms work ok. Its the stock browser that is not working.

Comment: The Android browser is Webkit based. Maybe the particular transform you're using is buggy on Android. I've used translateX and translateY.

Comment: Boom! First hit off of Google and -webkit-transform did the trick for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use the webkit prefixes and take care with media queries like "max-device-width: 360px" which doesn't work in some devices with this browser.
If some rule isn't working try to change max-device-width by max-width. It worked for me sometimes.